# Insert a 2d array as multiple rows in a SQLite database using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, sqlite, for-loop

This 2d array can be of any length so if for example the array is

```
var my_2D_Array = 
[['jack',22,'student'],
['Bob',45,'doctor'],
['bucky',30,'unelployed']]

// currently I am using this but it isn't working properly 

for(i=0;i<my_2D_Array.length;i++){
  clientChart.run(`INSERT INTO HP2255 VALUES (?, ?, ?)`,my_2D_Array[i],(err)=>{
  console.log('err' + err)
})
```

Is it possible to insert an array like this into the database with out using a for loop

I am really new to programming in general and if there is anything that I am missing than please help me out

Comment: You're passing an array to the query not 3 individual values and you aren't specifying which columns the VALUES reference, should be `INSERT INTO HP2255 (name, age, job) VALUES (?,?,?);`. Which sqlite library are you using?

Comment: sqlite3 in electron

Comment: You'll need the for loop, there is a clear example in the [Usage](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3#usage) section on the repo. I might recommend looking at [better-sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-sqlite3) though.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing more about your setup/table definition and based on the [Usage](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3#usage) presented in the repo I would guess something like the following:

```
const my_2D_Array = [
  ['jack', 22, 'student'],
  ['Bob', 45, 'doctor'],
  ['bucky', 30, 'unelployed'],
];

// explicitly declare columns (it may work without, but is more fragile and less clear)
const stmt = clientChart.prepare('INSERT INTO HP2255 (name, age, job) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
for (const row of my_2D_Array) {
  stmt.run(...row); // spread each sub-array to pass the individual elements
}
stmt.finalize();
```